# CPU usage very high

Tags: xubuntu, cpu

I have xubuntu 16.04 and sometimes my cpu usage is going crazy like in this picture:

[image]

The problem is that the process that is using the cpu it's not showing.

I don't know what causes this, I didn't find others with this problem. I don't know what information you need so tell me if you need more information. If I can't get it solved I will reinstall the os and hopefully it will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

The image is not very helpful in finding out the cause of your problem. However you can figure out what's causing the random CPU spikes by sorting the CPU usage in decreasing order, that way the process using the maximum amount of CPU will be on the top of the list. That will help you in solving the issue.

A wild guess will be a memory leak because of some driver. But check the CPU usage, that's the best way to figure out the core of the problem.

Comment: In the image the cpu was in decreasing order but no process with high cpu usage was appearing. This is the first thing I did but every time no process was appearing.

Comment: @E.Ionut that makes it difficult to track the source. It can be a glitch with the system installation or xfce4-taskmanager(during installation)